# Upload image file in Django REST framework with angularJS

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently uploading images through an API created by with Django REST framework with angularJS.
However, the problem is that it is stored as a media file but not stored in a database.

Here is my `ViewSet` code.

```py
# views.py

import time

from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from .serializers import UserSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = get_user_model()

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(profile_image=self.request.data.get('file'))
```

But, when I added the code `time.sleep(1)` before `serializer.save()` function, it was mysteriously saved to the database successfully.

```
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        time.sleep(1) # Delay 1s
        serializer.save(profile_image=self.request.data.get('file'))
```

Why does this happen? And please give me a wise solution.

I don't know if it would help, so I attached the angularjs code.

```
.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        return $http.patch(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
    }
  }])
```

This is my `User` model I was requested to share. I omitted the code that are not related to the error.
I confirmed that the image was saved in the path I specified. But not saved in database.

```py
# models.py

import datetime
import os

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models


def set_filename_format(now, instance, filename):
    return "{username}-{date}-{microsecond}{extension}".format(
        username=instance.username,
        date=now.date().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        microsecond=now.microsecond,
        extension=os.path.splitext(filename)[1],
    )


def profile_image_path(instance, filename):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    path = "profile_images/{username}/{year}/{month}/{day}/{filename}".format(
        username=instance.username,
        year=now.year,
        month=now.month,
        day=now.day,
        filename=set_filename_format(now, instance, filename),
    )
    return path


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # ...
    profile_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=profile_image_path,
        blank=True,
    )
    # ...
```

Comment: Can you share your models ? Above code is not clear.

Comment: @seenu s Of course. I shared my `User` model. Could you check it again, please?